# how to access linker symbol in c code with MinGW?

Tags: gcc, linker, mingw

I am using Mingw gcc and ld to generate an executable for windows.
I would like to access the start address of a section in c code, but I have tried a lot of methods and no one works.

My linker script file has this:

```
  .data BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    __data_start__ = . ;
    *(.data)
    *(.data2)
    *(SORT(.data$*))
    KEEP(*(.jcr))
    __data_end__ = . ;
    *(.data_cygwin_nocopy)
  }
```

In C code I do this:

```
extern char  __data_start__;
uint32_t  test = &__data_start__;
```

And get this error:
undefined reference to `__data_start__`

Could anyone help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: Some ABIs require a leading _ (underscore) for symbols, e.g. int foo() will give symbol _foo; hence for mingw32 defining `___data_start` (3 leading _'s) might do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but unfortunately this also does not work.

Comment: You see these symbols in the map file, i.e. in `x.map` when you link with `-Wl,-Map,x.map`?

Comment: Yes, I can see the symbol in the map file.

Comment: Strange, then the linker should be able to resolve them.  You can also add ```-save-temps``` to the ```gcc``` options and inspect the assembly file (```*.s```) that it defines respective symbol(s). These symbols are also in the object file (```*.o```) and are displayed by ```nm```.   There are cases with global optimizations where ```gcc``` makes the symbol from module.c local. In that case you can declare it with ```__attribute__((__externally_visible__))```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mingw32 is using leading underscores, i.e. the compiler will add a `_` (underscore) to each symbol.  The part of the linker description file you are showing is part of the default linker script (at least in my installation), and for your code I am getting the mentioned error for

```
int main()
{
    extern char __data_start__;
    return (int) &__data_start__;
}
```

with `-save-temps`, the assembly code has

```
    movl    $___data_start__, %eax
```

which has **3** leading `_`'s not just 2.

Thus, there are 2 solutions: You can advise the compiler to emit `__data_start__` as assembly name, which is a [GCC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Asm-Labels.html):

```
int main()
{
    extern char some_identifier __asm("__data_start__");
    return (int) &some_identifier;
}
```

Or you can use `_data_start`:

```
int main()
{
    extern char _data_start__;
    return (int) &_data_start__;
}
```

Both use `__data_start__` in assembly / object file:

```
    movl    $__data_start__, %eax
```

`i686-w64-mingw32-nm module.o`

```
         U __data_start__
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I used the second option and it solves my error.